# COM-interop class instance and optional parameters

Tags: c#, com-interop, optional-parameters

I have an instance of a COM-interop class generated by VS as a result of referencing an ActiveX DLL. One of the methods of the Interop class has a signature like

```
bool InteropClass.Method(params object[] Values)
```

Where the 'original' method (VB6 code) has a signature like

```
Method(ParamArray Values() As Variant) As Boolean
```

And I thought I could call it from C# like

```
interopClassInstance.Method("something", "something else", "something else");
```

But when I try to do it like that the compiler complains that `No overload for method 'Method' takes 3 arguments`. So, the only way I found that makes it work is to call it like

```
interopClassInstance.Method(new object[] {"something", "something else", "something else"});
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Isn't the `params` keyword supposed to enable the passing of *n* parameters?

Comment: `params` is a .NET-specific keyword that enables variable argument lists. COM does not support this keyword and therefor only the array get's exposed to the COM interface. The way you call the method (by creating an array) is the right way.

Comment: I think so too... I posted the question because it seems rather odd that the optional parameters from the source method are recognized as such by the framework when generating the Interop-class, but not marshaled correctly when invoking the method... It'd be more natural if the interop method had the signature `bool InteropClass.Method(object[] Values)`